# Error reading XLSX file in R

Tags: java, r

I'm trying to read an 1 MB XLSX file stored on a network drive using the lines

```
options(java.parameters="-Xmx4g")
library(rJava) 
library(xlsx) 
jgc <- function() {
  gc()
  .jcall("java/lang/System", method = "gc")
}    
jgc()
folder <- 'network_drive/State_Stuff/'  
state <- 'MI'
xlsx_in<- read.xlsx2(paste(folder, state,"_data.xlsx", sep = ""),
                  sheetName = "sheet1",
                  colClasses = c(rep("numeric",8), "character"))
```

And I get the following error.

`Error in .jcall("RJavaTools", "Ljava/lang/Object;", "invokeMethod", cl,  : 
  org.apache.poi.POIXMLException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException`

I'm running the Windows7 64-bit RStudio, and running `java -version` returns

```
java version "1.8.0_111"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_111-b14)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.111-b14, mixed mode)
```

I've tried copy/pasting the file onto my desktop from the network drive and reading that, but that throws the same error.

However, moving the file to my desktop, and using Save-As, and saving it as a new file allows me to read it just fine.

Does anyone have an idea on what's going on here?

Comment: The `openxlsx` library does not require java.

Answer (score 9):

Try using the `readxl` package. It doesn't depend on java.

So for example:

```
library(readxl) 

folder <- 'network_drive/State_Stuff/'  
state <- 'MI'
xlsx_in<- read_excel(paste(folder, state,"_data.xlsx"),
                  sheet = "sheet1",
                  col_types = c(rep("numeric",8), "text"))
```

Comment: Solved my issue where the problem may have been due to a large xlsx file (using a smaller file with less observations did not cause a problem)

Comment: Is there a similar package for writing to excel?

Comment: @cgage This works well: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/writexl/index.html

Comment: Thanks @boshek, I ended up using openxlsx package and it worked as well.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue today with a file I received from a colleague and came across this post while searching for a solution. Switching to a different library is not really a solution, and if you are used to xlsx, readxl has unexpected behaviors.

I was able to solve the problem by opening the file in Excel and resaving it. Not sure if the issue is produced by a particular version of Excel or anything else. I can read similar files from the same colleague just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Used gc() (Garbage Collection) and it works.

https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/gc

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please, don't post just a link to the relevant information. Links may become obsolete and then your answer would become worthless. Instead, post the relevant parts and/or examples as your answer.